# How to create database connection of Postgresql server in JSP project and eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, postgresql, jsp

Now, I'm a new starter on JSP Project and would like to create database connection between postgresql and in eclipse. So are there any solution to do on this?
Are there any file or library that I need to download?

The second question is that if we would like to create or build war file to run in Linux and window then how to build? How to do?

Very appreciate with your kindly help.
Thank you very much,
Best regards,
SmallCorner

Comment: Did you search on **Google** ?

Comment: @Sami, As I have checked in Google, there is no any source that really can help. Anywhere, if someone of our experts know the sources or link please help me.

Millions thanks..

Answer (score 0):

1. First Open a Dynamic Web Project in Java Eclipse.
2. Goto open perspective which is present at right top of IDE.
3. Click on Database development. (or) Go to Data Source Explore present at bottom panel.
4. Right click on it, then new, then type postgresql(name it).
5. next go to new driver definition, there add jar file of postgresql u have downloaded.
6. Finish.